# Can i make flash layer to affect only on other layer?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I have like a glint that goes over my stage and makes a shine effect on the text,

But i have a dark backround so you can see the glint gliding on the stage,

Can i somehow make the glint layer or glint Graphic symbol to affect only at my Text layer?

Comment: You can use the mask property of a display object

Answer (score 0):

Ungroup your text and put it into a movieClip named 'myText'. If the movieClip that makes a shine effect is named 'shineEffect', you can mask 'shineEffect' with 'myText':

```
shineEffect.mask = myText;
```

You set the mask object (myText) as a property of the object mask to hide (shineEffect).